# Blender crashes when saving files, installing plug ins

Tags: add-on, saving

I was trying to get back into blender after using another program for a while and a peculiar thing started occurring. When saving a file, even one containing just a simple cube and nothing else Blender crashed. Same thing happened when I tried to install a plug-in.

I'm using Blender 2.92 on Windows 10 Version 20H2, Intel i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz, GeForce GTX 1070

I already reinstalled Blender, the problem still persists. Would love to get some hints on what to do further - as I have no idea on how to deal with anything more complicated than restarting my computer.

Comment: Okay, blender is unable to write files. Try running it as administrator?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately running it as administrator changed nothing!